# How to fetch the amount spent by A Facebook Ad Account in a particular date range?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on creating a page where I display the amount spent by all the Ad Accounts linked to a Facebook Account, in the current month. I haven't been able to find a direct way to do it, so currently I'm fetching all the campaign details of each add account, then adding the amount spent in each campaign, and then displaying it. But it is a very long process. Is there a direct way of adding a date range to the total amount spent in an ad account?

**I am working with the PHP SDK.**

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: you could fetch the `spent` field in the [Ad Account, Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/) API

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution buddy

https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_yourAdAccountId/insights?fields=spend&date_preset=lifetime&level=account&access_token=yourAccessToken

date_preset values can be

- today,
- yesterday,
- this_month,
- last_month,
- this_quarter,
- lifetime,
- last_3d,
- last_7d,
- last_14d,
- last_28d,
- last_30d,
- last_90d,
- last_week_mon_sun,
- last_week_sun_sat,
- last_quarter,
- last_year,
- this_week_mon_today,
- this_week_sun_today,
- this_year